# How to disable caching from AFNetworking

Tags: caching, ios7, ios8, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to receive response from server. For first response, it works fine. However,  after I change the data on the admin site, and verify that the change is made in a browser, then I run the app again, but I still get the previous response. I don't understand why? It seems that AFNetworking is caching the old response. I want to download the current feed. Who can help me, please????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact opposite problem. I was getting the same image from my server twice, AFNetworking wasn't caching. As I debugged it I realized that I was calling 2 slightly different URLs, in one case I was specifying an option that was the default on the server.

So this gave me the idea for a work around hack for you. It isn't the right answer but it should work. Just pass a useless parameter to the server. Change this parameter for each server call.

https://example.com/myrequest?index=0

then

https://example.com/myrequest?index=1

where index is the unused parameter.

Note: this is actually a pretty gross hack, it should get you running but you really should find the "correct" answer.